# C#: Load TreeView with Images in UserControl WinForm

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2010, treeview

In the Winform, i have a UserControl TreeView and It loads real time data from XML file. The XML files loaded successfully in the treeView.

I want to generate TreeView with Different images for different sets of data. This link explains to generate treeview for specific array of data. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagelist][1]

How can I add different images for each parent and child nodes, in the XML, I want to add different images for `Global` `Files` `Section` and for `Data`. Please explain to me with some snippet.

```
<Global>
 <Files name="Bit_RunvsDepth" >
      <Section name="Linguini">
        <Data>measured depth</Data>
      </Section>
      <Section name="Process">
        <Data>Tree</Data>
        <Section name="Arguments">
          <Data>None</Data>
        </Section>
        <Section name="Extras">
          <Data>0.01</Data>
          <Data>Foodg</Data>
        </Section>
      </Section>
      <Section name="Color">
        <Data>0.0</Data>
      </Section>
      <Section name="MinScale">
        <Data>0</Data>
      </Section>
      <Section name="MaxScale">
        <Data>1000</Data>
      </Section>
    </Files>
</Global>
```

Comment: what are you using to parse xml? XmlReader, XmlDocument, XPathNavigator, XDocument?

Comment: @ alexm: I'm uisng `XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeNode class is not sealed, so you can build a hierarhy of custom node types.

```
     abstract class CustomTreeDataNode : TreeNode
     {
        public CustomTreeDataNode()
        {
        }   

        protected void ReadChildNodes<T>(XmlNode parent, string childNodeName)  
             where T: CustomTreeDataNode, new()
       {
              foreach(XmlNode node in parent.SelectNodes(childNodeName))
              {
                  T item = new T();
                  item.Fill(node);
                  Nodes.Add(item);
              }
       }

        public void Fill(XmlNode node)
        {
             Nodes.Clear();
             InitProperties(node);
        }

        protected abstract void InitProperties(XmlNode node);

     }

     class RootNode : CustomTreeDataNode
     {
        protected override void InitProperties(XmlNode source)
        {
            Text = "Root";
            ItemIndex = ROOT_ITEMINDEX;
            SelectedIndex = ROOT_SELECTEDINDEX;
            ReadChildNodes<FileNode>(source, "Files"));
        }
     }

     class FileNode : CustomTreeDataNode
     {
        protected override void InitProperties(XmlNode source)
        {
            Text = source["name"];
            ItemIndex = FILE_ITEMINDEX;
            SelectedIndex = FILE_SELECTEDINDEX;
            ReadChildNodes<SectionNode>(source, "Section"));
        }
     }  

     class SectionNode : CustomTreeDataNode
     {
        protected override void InitProperties(XmlNode source)
        {
            Text = source["name"];
            ItemIndex = SECTION_ITEMINDEX;
            SelectedIndex = SECTION_SELECTEDINDEX;
            ReadChildNodes<DataNode>(source, "Data"));
        }
     }  

     class DataNode : CustomTreeDataNode
     {
        protected override void InitProperties(XmlNode source)
        {
            Text = source.Text;
            ItemIndex = DATA_ITEMINDEX;
            SelectedIndex = DATA_SELECTEDINDEX;
        }
     }  

     ...
     RootNode root = new RootNode();
     root.Fill(rootXmlNode); 

     treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
```

To draw images TreeView relies on ImageView component. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.images) explains how to load images programmatically

Comment: How can i add images for tree selection?

Comment: @linguini You need to pre-load them into ImageList.

Comment: @linguini where do you get images from - are they available at compile-time ?

Comment: Just to verify, i load images from local drive. Should i add it to the imageList1???

Comment: If you can add them to image list in design-time, it would simplify the rest of the code. I actually made an assumption that this is what you were already doing..

Comment: @ alexm: How can i add them in design-time??, Could you explain a bit more??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12662/discussion-between-alexm-and-linguini)